# Why do applications storing instances global?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm not coming from the JavaScript world but in my leisure time I'm playing around with it. I'm using require.js. 
I saw very often that apps storing instances to the window object to get access from anywhere else. For my experience that using of global instances is a bad design. Am I wrong? For my application I don't need that so far. Maybe I owe that require.js, but I don't understand that using of global objects. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: Typically the best practice is to use as few globals as possible. But many people do not follow those guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Indiscriminately* populating (or "polluting") the global space with identifiers is indeed very problematic. The reason is simple: library A decides to declare its entry point as `main` in the global space, library B does the same thing and you have a clash. It can even happen that you need to load a single library more than once. A well known example is loading two versions of jQuery because one third party library needs version X and a second third party library needs Y. jQuery has the `noConflict` call to help manage this.

However, having *some* facilities defined in the global space is useful, when done in moderation. Consider that RequireJS when used in its default mode, exports `requirejs`, `require` and `define` to the global space. RequireJS is careful not to spill all of its internals into the global space, which is great. What is acceptable in what situation will vary depending on the developers involved and the specific application involved. For the applications I'm developing with RequireJS, I find it acceptable that RequireJS exports *only three symbols* into the global space. If I change my mind, there's a way to do prevent RequireJS from exporting directly to the global space (for instance, one possibility is optimizing with `r.js` while using the `namespace` setting, using the `almond` library is another possibility).